# Autenticação em Java EE

Tags: html5, java-ee, autenticação, nosql

estou desenvolvendo uma app cujo cliente será html5 + javascript (single-page-app) e o backend será basicamente jax-rs + cdi + nosql (glassfish & orientdb). Nesse cenário, preciso de ajuda para defiir como autenticar os usuários.

Os dados dos usuários estão na base orientdb. Sei que tenho que criar um algoritmo p/ conectar no bd e validar as credenciais do usuário, mas, para isso, devo criar um custom realm e um LoginModule por conta própria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em um servidor de aplicação como o GlassFish ou JBoss poderíamos resolver isso usando os mecanismos padrões de segurança. Para tanto basta que você crie um *connection pool*, um [JDBC realm](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxgo.html) e implemente [autenticação via form](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html).

#### Formulário:

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
  <input type="text" name="j_username">
  <input type="password" name="j_password">
</form>
```

#### Exemplo de `web.xml`

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Pages</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMINS</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Dito isso, esse modelo de autenticação pode não ser suficiente. Frameworks como [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) e [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) são comumente usados em aplicações Web para prover implementações mais completas e flexíveis de autenticação e autorização.

Comment: +1 por apresentar opções. O driver jdbc do orientdb é desatualizado. Também não vejo como criar um pool para ele no app server. Acho que assim não vai dar. As frameworks parecem interessantes, mas tenho como integrá-las no java ee sem ter de migrar pro spring?

Comment: André, tem sim. Você não precisa usar Spring no restante da sua aplicação (e o Apache Shiro também é stand alone). Sobre o driver do orientdb, realmente não tenho como responder, mas sobre o Pool não deve ter nenhum problema (apenas inclua o driver no Classpath e configure via console). Como as operações são muito babinhas (`select` pelo usuário, senha e  roles de determinado usuário) talvez o fato do driver ser velho não tenha grande impacto... Mesmo assim eu recomendo os Frameworks (vai chegar uma hora que você vai precisar de alguma feature mais avançada e ela fará falta :).

Comment: Obrigado, Anthony! Caso alguém queira criar seu próprio mecanismo de autenticação no glassfish4, saiba que é mais fácil do que parece. Aqui vai a [referência oficial](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-development-guide.pdf) e um [exemplo](https://github.com/martijnblankestijn/glassfish-jdbc-realm) que pode ajudar.